# Finding the source of a WebRequest in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently trying to build a Google Chrome extension where one of the features is to lazily request images based on whether or not they're above the fold. Using the `chrome.webRequest API` I'm able to add a listener before the web request for the image occurs using `onBeforeRequest`; however, I have no clue which DOM elements triggered the request. As a result, I don't know where on the page the request is coming from and therefore can't block the request until the client scrolls to the correct part of the page.

Here's my current code that catches the request:

```js
var hideImagesCallback = function lazyLoadImage(details) {
    console.log(details);
    return { cancel: false };
}

var hideImagesFilter = {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"],
    types: ["image"]
}

var hideImagesOptExtraInfoSpec = ["blocking"];


function hideImages() {
    // triggered when a web request for an image is started
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        hideImagesCallback, 
        hideImagesFilter, 
        hideImagesOptExtraInfoSpec
    );

    return "handler for images added";
}
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Any insights would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would simply use a content script to replace `src` of images with `data-lazy-src` for example and then load it using IntersectionObserver API. Why webRequest?

Comment: Would I be able to access the <img> element on the DOM before the webRequest is sent out? I'm generally concerned with minimizing the HTTP requests a page will make. I'll definitely check out the IntersectionObserver API too.

Comment: MutationObserver intercepts the elements on creation so when you blank out `src`, the request either won't be issued at all, or (in case the browser decided to prefetch the image) it'll be canceled.

Comment: Wow, just checked out the API and it looks like it will help out a lot! My only question is that when I change the `src`, how can I change it so that it defers the HTTP request based on the results from the IntersectionObserver API? I'm assuming that the value of `src` is generally a URL, so I don't know how to capture this in a URL.

Comment: Well, that's the usually complicated DOM stuff. Save the element's `src` in a different attribute like I suggested above. Also, you'll need to process srcset, `<source>` elements too.